# How to make redis throw exception on write error?

Tags: caching, redis

Even if there is issue in writing to disk during snapshoting, redis doesn't throw any errors. There are no errors related to write fail in redis server logs. It simply says `0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write` in logs. Therefore we are not able to figure out whether there is issue in writing to disk or everything is normal. Even if we manually remove write permission on path, it doesn't throw any error. My question is how to make redis throw error when there is issue in writing to disk? We want to do some automation whenever we detects errors in logs. Is there any settings we have to change to make redis throw error, in case if it is failed to write on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can set enable RDB snapshot, and configure `stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes`.

With this configuration, Redis stops accepting write requests once it fails to do background save on disk.

Comment: This will stop writing snapshot file from next time, if there is error while writing to disk. By my use case is, it should try to write and if there is a error, it should throw error and that error should be visible in logs.